# How can I center a Navbar in react-bootstrap

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am hoping that this is a simple question, and I see that some folks have asked a similar question about bootstrap. I haven't been able to work one of those answers into a solution that works for me, and I think there may be a simpler react-bootstrap answer in any case.

Code example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq5jvl9lz9

Here's what it looks like, when the viewport is wide enough:
[image: Navbar as produced by my Codesandbox code]

Here's more-or-less what I want:
[image: What I'm shooting for]

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks, Nat

EDIT 12/22/18: Starting with the information from @Cristian below, I modified the example. I needed `display: inline-block` in addition to `width: 100%`. Unfortunately, at larger screen sizes, the "brand" is now mis-aligned with the menu items:
[image: misaligned navbar]

Any other fixes appreciated! I have posted this as a [fresh question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900570/), so answers can go there (and points for accepted answer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's 1 year late but I had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825507/is-react-bootstrap-limited-in-functionality/53836899#53836899) and couldn't find an answer. I found out that inline css doesn't work for me, so I had to define a custom class which is used for styling.

The solution to your problem would be styling the navbar-brand or any other element by using `text-align: center` however, this will not work unless you also specify `width: 100%`. Please access the link I provided to see my approach to the problem.

**THIS IS AN EDIT AFTER OP'S LAST EDIT:**

I found two approaches to do what you want to achieve. One is not very responsive and I don't recommend.

First approach:

Delete everything in CSS and leave just

```
.center-navbar {
  width:30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
}
```

Second approach:

Delete everything in css and, instead you will be using the [layout grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) offered by React Bootstrap. Now your code in Index.js will be looking something like that:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, Glyphicon, Grid, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./index.css";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Grid>
      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col xs={4} md={4}>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={4} md={4}>
          <div>
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
              <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>Logo</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
              </Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav>
                  <NavItem eventKey="a" href="#">
                    Link1
            </NavItem>

                  <NavItem eventKey="b" href="#">
                    Link2
            </NavItem>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
    <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>This is some text</h2>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

There is a problem however. I recommend you to study W3C (World Wide Web consortium) and understand why it's not recommended to place Logo in the middle of the screen. If you look on most websites (Stackoverflow, Amazon, eBay, the list goes on), they don't use the logo in the middle, and instead on the left. It's a standard so that's why there is no much recommendation for that. I do not recommend to use the solution I offered unless that's exactly your only way to accomplish what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @cristian , not too late, I have not worked on this project in some time. I will look at this and get back here, hopefully, but I'm not sure exactly when.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer... It centers the menu, but unfortunately now the Logo is above the Link1 and Link2 parts. :-( I think I am giving up on this problem.

Comment: sorry mate, I have been away for holiday. Never give up, as long as you believe there is a solution.  I am not fully aware of your code, however maybe you added 'width 100%' to the logo rather than the entire div, therefore your logo taking the full width available to it!

Comment: No worries, mate! I hope your holiday was good.  width 100% is applied to the entire div, and to the container, but not the navbar. The code is here, if you have a moment to look at it and try things: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq5jvl9lz9. It works in the small window, but when you go to the full window (https://yq5jvl9lz9.codesandbox.io/), the issues appear. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Cristian, I will look this over when I have a chance, but it may be a little bit.

Comment: And how do you use this solution for the collapse case (on smartphones for example)? Then it also goes to the middle. Is it possible to do the css only for not collapsed cases?

Comment: ネディム Sushi Developer
You can play more with the xs and md to get the expected outcome. You want the css only for not collapsed cases? Doesn't look like a bootstrap problem so I would recommend a special question. Would be happy to help.

Answer (score 21):

I think `className='m-auto'` at `Nav` is enough

Comment: Thanks. How do we get this info? I cannot find it in react-bootstrap documentation.

Comment: m-auto worked for me.  I had it set to me-auto.  I need to brush up on that notation again...  Link to Bootstrap 5 notation explanation (which I had forgot)  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question, and this worked for me:

Add `className="justify-content-center"` to the parent.

Example:

```xml
<Navbar className="justify-content-center">
    <Navbar.Brand/>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap? This doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, you can use the Container from react-bootstrap around your navbar. It will align your navbar with the main section. On a screen, with a higher width, it will look much better! I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Putting the Navbar content in a `<Container>` worked for me, see snip.

**Using bootstrap v4.6, react v17 and react-bootstap v1.5**

```json
 "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
 "react": "^17.0.2",
 "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2"
```

**Snip from *Navigation.js*, see `<Container>` below:**

```js
render() {
  return (
 <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="sm"  fixed="top"
       className="bg-light justify-content-between">
     <Container>
       <LinkContainer to="/">
        <Navbar.Brand>
        <img src={my_image} alt='my alt text' className='profile-header'/>
        </Navbar.Brand>
       </LinkContainer>

       <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
       <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
         <Nav className="mr-auto">
             <LinkContainer to="/">
               <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
             </LinkContainer>
             <LinkContainer to="/about">
               <Nav.Link>About</Nav.Link>
             </LinkContainer>
             <LinkContainer to="/something" activeClassName='selectedMenuItem'>
               <Nav.Link>Something</Nav.Link>
             </LinkContainer>
             <Navbar.Text>
               <Title/>
             </Navbar.Text>
         </Nav>
       </Navbar.Collapse>
     </Container>
 </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just saw the problem that you have. I had the same issue. I just took the normal navbar from react-bootstrap, and switched the navbar brand with my logo. I added, using styled-components

```
margin-right: 35vw;
```

to the style of the logo. So it pushed all the links to the middle of the page. The code for the navbar you can find under https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/.

I hope it helps you.