# Is react-bootstrap limited in functionality?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I just started using react with [bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) and implemented a navbar. I can see that bootstrap has many functionalities, however I also see that it is limited in functionality, or, it doesn't give as much 'freedom' in terms of customization. I hope I am wrong but here is my example:

```
              <Grid>
                <Row className="text-center">
                   <h1>Our Products</h1>
                </Row>
              </Grid>
```

This code renders the `<h1>` in the middle of the screen no matter your device size. It works perfectly!

```
            <Navbar>
                <Navbar.Brand className="text-center">
                    <a className='menuItem' href="#home">Sample Text</a>
                </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar>
```

This is supposed to render a navigation bar with the `<Navbar.Brand>` in the middle of the screen. The problem is that it has no effect!

I also tried to apply style instead of the className, or even define my own className and work with it in a .css file but it never works. Is this a limitation of React Bootstrap?

I have been able to do something like this to put the text in the middle

```
            <Grid>
                <Row className="show-grid">
                    <Col xs={4} md={5}></Col>
                    <Col xs={4} md={5}>{this.props.children}</Col>
                    <Col xs={4} md={5}></Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
```

I would still like to know how to use the className="text-center" to place the `<Navbar.Brand>` in the center or, any way to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this problem is pretty common and in most cases has no answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565496/how-can-i-center-a-navbar-in-react-bootstrap), tried every solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838463/bootstrap-center-navbar-items) but didn't work). I found out that the only way to make it work is to define a custom-className and edit it in CSS. Weird is that it doesn't work with inline styling for me!

The code becomes:

```
<div>
                 <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Brand className="navbar-brand-custom">
                        <a href="#home"><p>Metanice</p></a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar>
</div>
```

with an external css

`.navbar-brand-custom {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }`

I also found out that it will never work if you don't specify the width

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the default text alignment inside a file named "App.css" that comes with React package

Comment: That's one of the ways however, I only want to do it on a specific page, so not apply it to everything